# Use fixed width number set in font

Tags: typography, monospace

Our branding has recently changed to use the [Hind](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Hind) font.

How can the fixed width numbers be used in applications like Excel?

[image]

Comment: Why can't they? Please describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: Well selecting the font in Excel for the dates `01/01/2017` and `02/02/2020` the first number set is being used so they display with different overall widths. How would you specify to use the second number set?

Comment: According to Microsoft it is sadly not possible. [Question and answer at microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/opentype-features-in-excel/39ef6999-9143-429e-af69-8f17b286589c?auth=1)

Comment: Could you put your comment as an answer and I will mark complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Microsoft states at microsoft.com:

"Excel doesn't support these advanced features, sorry. You'll have to use fonts that use tabular number spacing by default."

[Question and answer at microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/opentype-features-in-excel/39ef6999-9143-429e-af69-8f17b286589c?auth=1)